# Passing function pointer as an argument using va_args

Tags: c

I am trying to pass a function pointer as part of a number of arguments under va_arg.  I tried using a `void *` wildcard, before typecasting it later, but that gives an error.

```
   fn_ptr = va_arg(*app, (void*));
```

How does one pass a function pointer, as an argument to another function using `va_args`?

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the type of the function pointer to `va_arg`. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void foo()
{
    printf("foo\n");
}

typedef void(*foo_ptr)();

void bar(unsigned count, ...) 
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, count);
    unsigned i = 0;

    for (; i < count; ++i) {
        foo_ptr p = va_arg(args, foo_ptr);
        (*p)();
    }
    va_end(args);
}

int main() 
{
    bar(2, &foo, &foo);
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b42709273b52d71)

Comment: Great, thanks!  Realized that in the definition of `va_arg`, the second argument must not be bracketed i.e. `void *` instead of `(void *)` to work.

Comment: @jhtong According to the standard you're [not allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13697654/241631) to cast from a function pointer to `void *` and vice versa.